# Why F distrubution can't compute p < 2.2e-16 but anova can?

Tags: r

This thread
[Why can't I get a p-value smaller than 2.2e-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970705/why-cant-i-get-a-p-value-smaller-than-2-2e-16), begins to answer my problem however my issue is with using the F-distribution to generate p-value less than 2.2e-16.

```
1-pf(50,3,200)
[1] 0
```

My goal is to effectively mimic the `levene.test` from the `lawstat` package but wrapping the "lite" function in apply to allow 10-100,000 of calculation more efficiently. 
I have achieved this but have the issue with a few p-value < 2.2e-16. The `levene.test` function, which employs the `anova` function is able to deal with these.

Other than going back to my function and editing it to using the `anova` function over `pf`, does anyone have any ideas why the `pf` is limited by `anova` isn't. 
If I use the `anova` function it would double the runtime

Comment: And you need to generate p-values less than 2.2e-16 because...? I'm not trying to be unhelpful here but from a statistical point of view, why?

Comment: I understand the precision of the pvalue here may seem pointless, however in my field there is often adjustments for multiple testing > 100000. There is also the requirement to visualize some of these observations. I'm not too concerned about these p-values, but I was trying to understand why some functions can work around the lower limit threshold, and if I can implement those work arounds

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't sound sensible at all. Multiple testing corrections for 10^5 tests is still 11 orders of magnitude (!!) smaller than the precision of your p-value. So that won't make any difference. Btw, in my area of work we often work with similar testing scenarios. In my personal opinion, there is very little point in reporting p-values less than e.g. 10^-5. Multiple testing corrections is a whole new can of worms that I'd avoid at all cost, especially for that many tests that are probably not all independent.

Comment: I completely agree with everything you are saying and I'm not stressed about losing any precision below 2.2e-16. The reason this problem arose was trying to plot some -log10(p). I have no illusions that there is no statistical merit in gaining any more precision, but was rather curious at how the functions (`anova`, `t.test` etc) were getting around this

Comment: In response to your question: You can see the [smallest positive floating-point number](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/zMachine.html) on your machine with `.Machine$double.eps` which I imagine will be (around) 2.2e-16. So this is a simple result of (limited) machine precision.

Comment: @MauritsEvers:  You missed an important part of the definition of `.Machine$double.eps`:  it's the smallest positive floating-point number x *such that 1 + x != 1*.  The last part is important; R can easily hold numbers like `1e-300`, but `1 + 1e-300 == 1`.

Comment: @George:  If you posted code there might be the possibility of help but at the moment it's not possible, for me anyway, to understand what you are attempting. There is a `log.p` parameter to `pf` that you have not yet exploited.

Comment: @user2554330 Yes I am perfectly aware of that; `.Machine$double.eps` gives you the precision of numbers *close to zero*. That is exactly what matters here. You can see the minimum-representable normalized positive floating-point value with `.Machine$double.xmin`. There is a [really useful post with some excellent answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847918/extreme-numerical-values-in-floating-point-precision-in-r) here on SO that provides a lot of details.

Comment: @MauritsEvers:  I believe you are aware of all of this, but you aren't expressing it clearly.  `.Machine$double.eps` is *not* the precision of numbers close to zero, it's the precision of numbers close to one.

Comment: @user2554330 You are absolutely right, and I did indeed express it poorly. Thanks for the clarification.